# Multiples get_or_create in loop with inner loop, database performance issue (Entity-Attribute-Value model)

Tags: django, database, performance

I have the following Django models:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True, db_index=True)


class AirtableProduct(models.Model):
    internal_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class AirtableProductPropertyValue(models.Model):
    airtable_product = models.ForeignKey(AirtableProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='properties')
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('airtable_product', 'property'),)
        index_together = [
           'airtable_product', 'property'
        ]
```

They represent an object (AirtableProduct) identified by an internal_id and with a variable number of properties that I represent with the Property and AirtableProductPropertyValue tables.

The problem comes with the following piece of code, when creating/updating a product and its properties:

```
// products is an array of dictionary with the properties as key/value
def insert_all_airtable_products(products):
    logger.info('Inserting Airtable products into the database')

    for product in products:
        internal_id = product.pop('Internal ID')
        ap, created = AirtableProduct.objects.get_or_create(internal_id=internal_id)

        for field in product:
            property, created = Property.objects.get_or_create(
                name=strip_spaces(field)
            )

            ap_pv, created = AirtableProductPropertyValue.objects.get_or_create(airtable_product=ap, property=property)
            ap_pv.value = strip_spaces(product[field])
            ap_pv.save()
```

I have 10,000 products, each one with 20+ properties, given that I have to loop through each product and update/create old/new properties the cost of this operation is high it's taking a lot of time for the database.

How can make it better?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all the AirtableProducts from the database along with their AirtableProductPropertyValue and Property, store them in a dictionary and use them to instead of get_or_create.

You can also use bulk_create instead of calling object.save() every time. Following code illustrates it:

```
airtable_product_dict = {}
queryset = AirtableProduct.objects.prefetch_related(
'properties', 'properties__property')

for airtable_product in queryset:
    airtable_product_dict[airtable_product.internal_id] = airtable_product

new_aritable_products = []

for product in products:
    internal_id = product.pop('Internal ID')
    if internal_id not in aritable_product_dict:
        new_airtable_products.append(AirtableProduct(internal_id))

    # Follow similar logic ahead

AirtableProduct.objects.bulk_create(new_airtable_products)
```

Note:

1. Your fields auto_now_add and auto_add will not be populated when using bulk_create, consider adding them in constructor.
2. This code is not thread safe and will likely have inconsistent state if two threads are running it simultaneously.
3. Consider reading Django [db optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/optimization/).